# MVVM Light messaging from child to parent

Tags: mvvm-light

Is it possible to raisepropertychanged for an ObservableCollection from a child viewmodel ?
I have a child viewmodel which inserts a new item in a ObservableCollection from a parent ViewModel and I need to raisepropertychanged on that collection for refreshing a list binded to it.
What I need is to view in that list the new item already added.
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can Use Messneging service to send and register Value form one view/ViewModel/Class to any View/Viewmodel/Class. You can use like You can use the Token while sending and registering Messaging.

Suppose You have to pass Message From ViewModel to ABCView then you can use Messenging like this..

For Ex:

```
Messenger.Defalut.Send<ObservableCollection<string>>(obj,"ForAbcView");
```

And in ABCView you can register like this:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<ObservableCollection<string>>(this,"ForAbcView",(b)=>{ //Some Code });
```

With using Token the Messenger Sender will only looks for the Register which will have same token. It only calls the method which will have same tocken.

This way you can send the collection to any palce You want.